# can the fast report toolbar icons be completely replaced?

Tags: fastreport

I'm working with fast report and I would like to change their default preview toolbar.

I need to replace some of the icons with icons of my own, **and**  I need the ability to add my own custom buttons.

I looked at this [thread](http://goo.gl/VB5uy) from their support.

It mentions how to just change the icons to other fast-report provided icons, but I need to put in custom icons and add new buttons.

Has anyone done this before? Or knows whether this is possibly with FastReport.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. See this article on how to do it http://sensasi40.com/tutorials/135-creating-fastreport-custom-preview.html

Comment: Broken Link. Another one, https://www.fast-report.com/en/blog/show/custom-report-toolbar/

Answer (score 1):

If you have the professional edition of fastreports you have access to the source code.
I have heard of people editing this and recompiling to create thier own custom preview window